# Custom Control, bind to code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Having trouble binding to the data in my code behind for my custom control. Obviously I have got to use the `Generic.xaml` to style my control, and I want to bind to the data in my control `UserProfile.cs`.

This is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Controls
{
    public class UserProfile : Control
    {
        static UserProfile()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UserProfile), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UserProfile)));
        }

        private Double _ProfilePhotoSize = 50;
        private Double ProfilePhotoSize
        {
            get { return _ProfilePhotoSize; }
            set
            {
                if (_ProfilePhotoSize != value)
                    _ProfilePhotoSize = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML with the binding, removed the last part as it isn't needed:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Controls">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NumericUpDown}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colour1" Color="#434953" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colour2" Color="#22252b" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colour3" Color="#606876" />
        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="Width" Value="85" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NumericUpDown}">
                    <Border Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            x:Name="Border">
                        <Grid Focusable="False">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Button x:Name="PART_DecreaseButton" 
                                    Grid.Column="0">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Path Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1Z"
                                          Fill="White"
                                          Width="8"
                                          Height="6"
                                          Stretch="Fill"/>
                                </Button.Content>
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Border Name="Border"
                                                Background="{DynamicResource colour1}" 
                                                Width="25" 
                                                Height="25"
                                                CornerRadius="5 0 0 5">
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource colour3}" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>

                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     Foreground="White"
                                     Background="{DynamicResource colour2}"
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                     BorderThickness="0"
                                     Focusable="False" Text="0" />

                            <Button x:Name="PART_IncreaseButton" 
                                    Grid.Column="2">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Path Data="M0,1 L1,1 0.5,0Z" 
                                          Width="8"
                                          Height="6"
                                          Fill="White" 
                                          Stretch="Fill" />
                                </Button.Content>
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Border Name="Border" 
                                                Background="{DynamicResource colour1}" 
                                                Width="25" 
                                                Height="25"
                                                CornerRadius="0 5 5 0">
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource colour3}" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Type local:UserProfile}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}">
                    <Grid x:Name="circleGrid" Width="{Binding Path=ProfilePhotoSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserProfile}}}">
...
```

This is the binding error i'm getting:

> BindingExpression path error: 'ProfilePhotoSize' property not found on
>   'object' ''UserProfile' (Name='')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ProfilePhotoSize; DataItem='UserProfile'
>   (Name=''); target element is 'Grid' (Name='circleGrid'); target
>   property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

**Edit:**
Just moved some code around and getting issue with the code now, I want to the border size to adjust based on the size the user makes the control, so I have made a new class and property which gets the `ProfilePhotoSize` and then will divide it by a number.

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Controls
{
    public class UserProfile : Control
    {
        static UserProfile()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UserProfile),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UserProfile)));
        }
    }
    public class UserProfileData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private Double _ProfilePhotoSize = 50;
        public Double ProfilePhotoSize
        {
            get { return _ProfilePhotoSize; }
            set
            {
                if (_ProfilePhotoSize != value)
                    _ProfilePhotoSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProfilePhotoSize");
            }
        }
        private Double _ProfileBorderThickness = 3;
        public Double ProfileBorderThickness
        {
            get { return _ProfileBorderThickness; }
            set
            {
                double x = ProfilePhotoSize / 3;
                if (_ProfileBorderThickness != x)
                    _ProfileBorderThickness = x;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProfileBorderThickness");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XAML, binding no longer works :S

**XAML**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Controls">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Type local:UserProfile}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}">
                    <Grid x:Name="circleGrid" Width="{Binding ProfilePhotoSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserProfileData}}}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to a public property.

```
    private Double _ProfilePhotoSize = 50;
    public Double ProfilePhotoSize
    {
        get { return _ProfilePhotoSize; }
        set
        {
            if (_ProfilePhotoSize != value)
                _ProfilePhotoSize = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake that was, I didn't even think to check that.. thanks!

Comment: Heh, no worries. Number of times I've lost half hour to that... >.< Doesnt happen as much any more though, I use a snippet for my properties, might be useful :P https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Comment: Not sure, but DataContext is set to UserProfile - Should it not be set to UserProfileData? Not sure but thats my best guess?

Comment: I have no idea then, sorry :(